# Some useful cucumber/capybara expressions for Material API in Angular

Tags: cucumber, angular-material, angular5, capybara-webkit

I have started working with the latest Angular (5) and Material and have come across some useful functions to help with testing.

Here is my "material.rb" file:

```
Given("she clicks chip {string}") do |name|
   find("mat-chip", :text => name).click()
end

Given("eventually there are {int} grid tiles") do |count|
   eventually { expect(find('mat-grid-list > div')).to have_selector('mat-grid-tile', count: count.to_i) }
end

Given("eventually in modal dialog there are {int} grid tiles") do |count|
   eventually { expect(find('.modal-dialog mat-grid-list > div')).to have_selector('mat-grid-tile', count: count.to_i) }
end

When("she clicks action {string} in card with title {string}") do |action, title|
   find("mat-grid-tile mat-card-title", :text => title).find(:xpath, "../../..").find("mat-card-actions > button > span", :text => action).click()
end

When("she clicks action number {int} in card with title {string} in modal dialog") do |action, title|
   find(".modal-dialog mat-grid-tile mat-card-title", :text => title).find(:xpath, "../../..").find("mat-card-actions > button:nth-child(#{action})").click()
end

When(/^a modal dialog appears$/) do
   find(".modal-dialog")
end

When(/^eventually the modal dialog disappears$/) do
  eventually { has_no_css?(".modal-dialog") }
end
```

The .modal-dialog is my own tag I put on all modal dialogs, but you could replace this with "mat-dialog-container".

And here is a few steps to show how I use them:

```
@javascript
Scenario: A new idea can be created in a stream
   When she clicks "MyQ"
   And she clicks "New Idea in a stream"
  And a modal dialog appears
   And she clicks chip "Stream 1"
  And she enters "New Task 1" in "name"
  And she enters "Do this" in "description"
  And she clicks "Ok"
  And eventually the modal dialog disappears

   @javascript
    Scenario: A non-empty team cant be deleted
       When she clicks action "DELETE" in card with title "Team 1"
      And a modal dialog appears
      And she clicks "Ok"
      And eventually the modal dialog disappears
      And a modal dialog appears
      And she clicks "Ok"
      Then eventually the modal dialog disappears
      And eventually there are 2 grid tiles
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a number of issues with these as suggestions for other people.  Firstly `eventually` just isn't necessary since all Capybara's matchers and most of its finders have waiting/retrying behavior.  So either increase `Capybara.default_max_wait_time` or specify a `wait` parameter in the call to increase the maximum time it will wait for the matcher/expectation/find to succeed. Secondly you should turn all the "in xxx" into their own steps that use Capybaras scoping and then call other steps, so they're reusable, and thirdly you should use expectations rather than finds to make it clear what you're actually testing. Implementing all of these gives something along the lines of

```
Given("she clicks chip {string}") do |name|    
  find("mat-chip", :text => name).click() 
end

Given("eventually there are {int} grid tiles") do |count| 
  expect(find('mat-grid-list > div')).to have_selector('mat-grid-tile', count: count.to_i, wait: 20) # wait up to however long "eventually" can be
end

Given("{string} in modal dialog") do |modal_step|
  within(".modal-dialog") do
    step(step_in_modal)
  end
end

When("{step} in card with title {string}") do |card_step, title|
   within("mat-grid-tile mat-card-title", text: title) do
     step(card_step)
   end
end

When("she clicks action {string}") do |action|
  find(:xpath, "../../..").find("mat-card-actions > button > span", :text => action).click()
end

When("she clicks action number {int}") do |action|
  find(:xpath, "../../..").find("mat-card-actions > button:nth-child(#{action})").click()
end

When(/^a modal dialog appears$/) do
 expect(page).to have_css(".modal-dialog")
end

When(/^the modal dialog disappears$/) do
  expect(page).to have_no_css?(".modal-dialog") # pass `wait` option if you need a longer time here and don't want to increase `Capybara.default_max_wait_time`
end
```

Comment: I think changing the default wait time for capybara is a rookie mistake. Using the word "eventually" in the test is actually for the CONSUMER of the test, not the implementation. If you expect something to happen instantly, use the default wait that should timeout quickly. If you want to tell the end user that there WILL be a wait, then implementing your own looper is a really good idea (and putting "eventually" in the test). The fact that you can achieve the same ends by using a little ruby code is a bonus :-)

Comment: Also, changing the default wait will just mean your tests will fail far slower if there is something actually wrong which really sucks.

Comment: @PaulHamilton Writing your own looper is pointless, when you need longer maximum wait times just specify the `wait` parameter for that call, not to mention you end up with better error messages than the way most people write `eventually` type methods.  As for `default_max_wait_time` - yes it should be set to the minimal level for normal behaviors, and then overwritten with the `wait` parameter on specific calls or `using_wait_time` for blocks - otherwise your tests may take longer to fail, but tests shouldn't be failing and it's better to have reliably passing tests than flaky failing ones